# Android temporarily disable / freeze invalidation of UI

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm updating my UI from code and from traceview it's apparent that most of the time is spent invalidating the user interface. I have about 20 textviews for which I set the sizes, and each setTextSize call invalidates the layout. Is there a way to disable layout in the start of the method, do my changes, and then force the view to invalidate?

In Windows Forms I could call BeginUpdate() and EndUpdate() on some controls - is similar functionality here?